# To run cucumber java project without maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I am performing automation setup using java, cucumber and junit. However, due to restrictions of firewall and proxy in company, not able to create maven project with archtype templates. Hence initially created java project with source folder as src/test/java, placed feature file, stepdefinition and test runner class within this source folder, however, while running test runner class, I am facing "test class not found error for selected project".
I tried all sort of solutions such as ordering JRE file to bottom, giving entire path of feature file,adding output folder in using run configuration etc however it seems not working.

Hence finally would like to know whether can we run cucumber with only java and junit in the absence of maven.

Kindly help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton. Put features in the resources folder. Otherwise they're not put on the classpath.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, no maven at all. That's going to be a bit trickier.